# how to delete list view in adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a `ListView` and I can delete data, but if I insert again the data comes back. How can I delete the data permanently from my list?

this code my activity

```
public class ListPesanan extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_pemesanan);
        /*
         * Ambil datanya yang ada di database dan serahin ke Adapter biar dia
         * aja yang ngurusin semuanya
         * 
         * Kita percaya aja sama Adapternya :D
         */

        PesananAdapter adapter = new PesananAdapter(this,
                DatabaseTemp.getPesanan(), DatabaseTemp.getJumlah(),
                DatabaseTemp.getBayar());
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and this code my adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pesan_item, parent, false);

        holder.editTextHarga = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextHarga);
        holder.editTextJumlah = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextJumlah);
        holder.editTextPesanan = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextPesanan);
        holder.Hapus = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.deletebutton);

        if (view != null) {
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
    } else holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    holder.editTextHarga.setText(hargaPesanan.get(position));
    holder.editTextJumlah.setText(jumlahPesan.get(position));
    holder.editTextPesanan.setText(pesanan.get(position));

    holder.Hapus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        pesanan.remove(position);
        jumlahPesan.remove(position);
        hargaPesanan.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        DatabaseTemp.delete();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you call `notifyDataSetChanged();` after `DatabaseTemp.delete();`?

Comment: @codeMagic in database empty, i insert listview again and look listview but data deleted come back, confused

Answer (score 0):

did you try the clear() method ?

If I take your code it will be like :

```
DatabaseTemp.clear();
```

Comment: delete success but if i go to listview again, data comeback

Comment: not work, if listview deleted and i come back to listview, data come back to listview

Comment: try something like yourlist.clear(); or adapter.clear(); and after notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
   pesanan.remove(position);
   jumlahPesan.remove(position);
   hargaPesanan.remove(position); 
   pesanan.clear();
   jumlahPesan.clear();
   hargaPesanan.clear();
   DatabaseTemp.delete();
   notifyDataSetChanged(); not work, if i insert data again, data deleted come back, pesanan, hargapesanan,jumlahpesanan is array list